# In MySql is there a way to compare a value to only the digits in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

When the user enters part of a phone number I need to compare and find matching records for that partial phone number.  The problem I have is that everyone enters their phone numbers differently.

```
(555) 123-4567
(444)333-2222
1.800.876.9000
1-555-333-1111
etc. etc. and on and on.
```

So my idea is that if there is a way to remove any and all punctuation from the field in the database I could then compare easily to whatever the user chooses to search by...555 or 9000 or 123.

Is there a way to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE {only the digits of the phone column} LIKE '%searchValue%'
```

Comment: Try the `RegExp` command. Look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: you could remove these symbols before saving it to the database or force the users to use one of the given formats

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum with all due respect, that simply is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that as I figured there is something really easy that I missed...

```
SELECT *
FROM person p 
WHERE REPLACE(phone, '[^0-9]+', '') LIKE '%555123%';
```

Does exactly what I want.  If there is a more efficient and faster query way to do this please let me know!

Comment: Your solution is going to be slow on large tables because every row in the table must be scanned.  You're unable to use indexes.

Comment: Andy Is there another way?

Comment: You told @ExpectoPatronum that you couldn't remove the symbols before saving to the database, but I bet you could create a second column like `phonedigits` that is without the symbols.  Even then, however, you can only do a LIKE without a % at the beginning to match, or else the index won't get used.  Read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ for all sorts of good stuff about indexing.